# error while using amsmath package

Tags: sectioning, amsmath

I try to run this:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\section}{
        \@startsection
            {section}{1}{0mm}
        {\baselineskip}%
        {\baselineskip} 
        {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}        
       }%
       \makeatother 
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{A}
    \end{document}
```

and I get a message that something's wrong with '.toc' file, so what's wrong? Why does this not like `amsmath` package?

Comment: @egreg's answer was quicker by half a second, and more complete so I removed mine.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick button below the voting arrows on the left side. By doing so you will conclude the question. If there is still something missing in the answer please state so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It subtly depends on the fact that `amsmath` redefines `\@ifnextchar`. In practical terms, you have a spurious space that the kernel version of that internal command removes, while the `amsmath` version doesn't.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
}
\makeatother
```

Notice particularly the last `%` that masks the end-of-line (equivalent to a space, here). The end-of-lines from the `\@startsection` line until the last one need not to be masked, because `\@startsection` will be looking for arguments and so ignore the spaces. Putting `%` there does no harm, anyway.

By the way, redefining `\thesection` is not the best method for adding a period after the section number in a heading:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
```

is better, because `\ref` won't produce the number followed by a period when referring to a section number. So, here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\baselineskip}
    {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
       }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 'because \ref won't produce the number followed by a period when referring to a section number' it's just an answer to the next question I had, thanks! ;)

Comment: @myname Welcome to TeX.SX, where somebody has a crystal ball that sometimes works. :)